# In semantic segmentation using Fully convolutional networks, why is Cross Entropy loss preferred over L1 or L2 losses?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization

I am training a fully convolutional network with Encoder-Decoder architecture for the task of Image Segmentation and currently am using the Binary Cross Entropy loss for foreground/background prediction.

I was trying to search and read about why Cross entropy loss is used instead of L1 or L2 losses. Cross entropy loss fails to capture the overall layout of the image, whereas L1 and L2 take the overall image reconstruction into account.

Comment: what do you mean by "overall image reconstruction"? ... particularly the word "overall"?

Comment: "Overall" means taking the entire semantics as a whole into account. The influence of nearby pixels and shapes as a whole.

Comment: both L1/2 and cross-entropy are "pointwise" losses though -- none of them take into account any nearby pixels and shapes.

Comment: Is there any way to take the influence of nearby pixels and shapes into account?

Comment: what would be the point of that?

Comment: Wouldn't that improve the segmentation? Since the value of the prediction is also influenced by neighbouring pixels.